# I can't add an external tester in TestFlight because the Add button is greyed out

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to add an external tester in TestFlight, but the Add button is greyed out:

[image]

Is this because the app hasn't yet been approved by Apple, or some other reasons?

I tried in both Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and Safari 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) on macOS 10.12.5.

This same person is beta-testing another of my apps, so I'm sure the problem is not regarding their account or mine, just the particular app I'm trying to add them as a tester to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pasted the email address in the "Last Name" field. Simply move the mail to the first textbox with the "Email" label above.

Comment: What a dumb mistake I made! Thanks. BTW, you don't need a first or last name.

Comment: Lol, I feel really stupid now. Had the same problem and just recognized this after finding this question via Google  Thanks!

Comment: Me too lol. Did not notice that the first field was email. Gets an upvote from me.

Comment: Wow, same here. But honestly this is (once again...) Apple's mistake. Everyone is expecting firstname - lastname - email . God, Apple...